Intercept redirect request
I have a problem with ios part of my application. I need to redirect to start page (content tag in config.xml) when backend is redirecting me to certain url. I don't have access to backend implmentation so i need to use this what it is doing. On Android I'm using onOverrideUrlLoading method in my plugin. On iOS i want to use shouldOverrideLoadWithRequest but I've got a problem. When I'm intercepting redirect it is redirecting to startup page but two alert are showing. One with message "frame load interrupted" and second which has information that I can't redirect. I don't know how to face this.
Below  I've paste code which I've write:
- (BOOL)shouldOverrideLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSRange range = [request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@".*mobile.html.*"
                                                      options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSURLRequest* redirectReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"httpsionic://localhost" cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0]
        [self.webViewEngine loadRequest:redirectReq]
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

Can someone could help me how to achieve this that I will be redirected to start page when something is returned in backend?
Maybe there is some methods which should be used in WKWebview?
